# Row is inserted into database everytime I refresh the jquery mobile page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, jquery-mobile

I am making a jquery mobile web app and I am using a multi page layout. I connect to mySQL when the page loads and on the second div page, I have a form which using a php file sends the values in the form to mySQL database when submitted.

My problem is, everytime I refresh the web app, a row is inserted into a table in my database. I obviously don't want this to occur until I click/tap the Submit button. I'm relatively new to web app development and would like any help as to what I'm doing wrong.

Advice on how best to insert to a mySQL database through php on a multi-page layout would be great. Please let me know if I need to show more code.

```
<!--Top of second page within multi page layout containing form-->
<!-- The POST A JOURNEY page where user creates a journey to be seen by others-->
    <div data-role="page" id="postAJourney" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="back" data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="flip" data-theme="b" >
        <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Post A Journey</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="add_journey.php" method="post" id="postAJourneyForm">

<!--Top of multipage layout-->
<?php
require 'database.php';
?>
```

UPDATED AGAIN

```
<?php

//get the journey data
$radUserType = intval($_POST['radUserType']);
$pjFrom = $_POST['pjFrom'];
$pjTo = $_POST['pjTo'];
$radioJourneyType = intval($_POST['radioJourneyType']);
$departDate = $_POST['departDate'];
$returnDate = $_POST['returnDate'];
$textareanotes = $_POST['textAreaNotes'];

//check all values from $_POST
$canSubmitForm = false;
$isFormEmpty = false;

if (empty($radUserType) || empty($pjFrom) || empty($pjTo) || empty($radioJourneyType) || empty($departDate) || empty($returnDate) || empty($textareanotes))
{
$isFormEmpty = true;
}

//check for your data here
if(isset($radUserType) && isset($pjFrom) && isset($pjTo) && isset($radioJourneyType) &&     isset($departDate) && isset($returnDate) && isset($textareanotes))
{
$canSubmitForm = true;
}

$departTime = '11:12';
$returnTime = '11:16';
$seatcounter = '2';

//will only get executed if true
if ($canSubmitForm)
{
if ($isFormEmpty == false)
{
require_once('database.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO journey
    (from_destination,to_destination,journey_type,depart_date,depart_time,return_date,return_time,seats_available,journey_message,user_type)
        VALUES('$pjFrom','$pjTo','$radioJourneyType','$departDate','$departTime','$returnDate','$returnTime','$seatcounter','$textareanotes','$radUserType')";
$db->exec($query);
// Perform Query
//$result = mysql_query($query);
//if($result === true)
//{
//  $result = 'success';
//}
//else
//{
//  $result = 'insertion failure' . mysql_error();
//}
include('index.php');
}
}
else
{
$error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
include('error.php');
}
//Display the Product List page
?>
```

Comment: Yes, show us how he form is being handled.

Comment: Class one: only search/get data with HTTP-GET method. Use POST for insert/update/delete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out the Insert logic and check if the form is valid and ready to submit.

pseudo code:

```
// check all values from $_POST
$canSubmitForm = false;

// check for your data here
// might want to verify type as well
if (isset($radUserType) && isset($pjFrom) && isset($pjTo) && isset($radioJourneyType))
{
    $canSubmitForm = true;
}

// will only get executed if true
if ($canSubmitForm)
{
    require_once('database.php');
    $query = "INSERT INTO journey
              (from_destination,to_destination,journey_type,depart_date,depart_time,return_date,return_ti      me,seats_available,journey_message,user_type)
              VALUES('$pjFrom','$pjTo','$radioJourneyType','$departDate','$departTime','$returnDate','$re    turnTime','$seatcounter','$textareanotes','$radUserType')";

    $db->exec($query);
    // Perform Query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // the rest of your code here 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Phill. I am now checking if the form is valid before submitting. However, if I leave my form elements empty, it still does the insert to database. Then it redirects with the url http://localhost/share/add_journey.php which is blank. I'll show my updated php above

Comment: You might need to also check for null, blanks, etc... or check for values as well

Comment: Ya your right. Thanks. I updated the add_journey.php to check for nulls also. I'm still confused as to why after I submit I get redirected to localhost/share/add_journey.php, which is blank. When I refresh this page, then I see my error message.